# How to add small delay to javascript tag

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I'd like to improve the load of my website. I've a Google Review script that is not necessary immediately upon opening the site. How do I make it load the JavaScript after 4-5 seconds?

```
<div id="brb_collection_297"></div><script type="text/javascript">!function(e){var c=document.createElement("script");c.src=e,document.body.appendChild(c)}("https://test.com?cf_action=brb_embed&brb_collection_id=297&brb_callback=brb_"+(new Date).getTime());</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` and wrap the function in another func:

```js
const loadScript = () => {
    !function(e){
        var c=document.createElement("script");
        c.src=e,document.body.appendChild(c)
        console.log("script loaded")
    }("https://test.com?cf_action=brb_embed&brb_collection_id=297&brb_callback=brb_"+(new Date).getTime())
}

setTimeout(loadScript, 400)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do you add the code below? I tried putting it in under <head> but it just adds the code on the top of my page. And do I need to add <script> or anything? Is 400 the delay, 400 ms?

Comment: Not sure what framework you're using, but Javascript usually goes inside the head tags or inside the body tags at the very bottom. You need to wrap it in an opening and closing script tag <script>...code...</script>. 400 is 400 milliseconds, correct.

Comment: I use WordPress. I tried to add it like this (with my other header scripts). There is no error, but the script doesn't show. 

<script>const loadScript = () => {
    !function(e){
        var c=document.createElement("script");
        c.src=e,document.body.appendChild(c)
        console.log("script loaded")
    }("https://test.com?cf_action=brb_embed&brb_collection_id=297&brb_callback=brb_"+(new Date).getTime())
}

setTimeout(loadScript, 400)</script>

Comment: @eMikkelsen Sorry I'm not sure. You may want to post an additional question about this

Comment: The issue seems to be with the way it is wrapped/the edit to the script. The script works when applied without anything (as in my post). But once adding the functions you presented, it stops working.